# How to return the list if they exist in both csv files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have 2 csv files, news.csv(the main csv file) and dictionary1.csv I am able to find out if the term in news.csv exist in any of the dictionary csvs,by returning 1 for exist and 0 for not exist, below are my codes:

```
news=pd.read_csv("news.csv")
dictionary=pd.read_csv("dictionary1.csv")

pattern='|'.join(dictionary['Lists'])

news["exist/not exist"] = np.where(
    news["STORY"].str.contains(pattern, na=False, case=False),
    1, 0
)
```

But, I couldn't figure out, how I can return the lists that matched from the 2 csvs. Below are my news.csv sample

```
ID  STORY
1   The weather today is Sunny, but tomorrow it is expected to be rainy
2   In  UK, there are 4 seasons, winter,summer, autumn and spring
3   Food is essential in life
```

My dictionary1.csv sample

```
Lists
Sunny
Rainy
Winter
Summer
Spring
Autumn
```

The output I wanted is

```
ID  STORY                                                                  exist/not exist    similar
1   The weather today is Sunny, but tomorrow it is expected to be rainy         1              sunny, rainy
2   In  UK, there are 4 seasons, winter,summer, autumn and spring               1              winter,summer,autumn,spring
3   Food is essential in life                                                   0               -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary escape strings with `re.escape` for correct parsing special regex characters and then is added `/b/b` for words boundaries - extracted values between spaces.

Then use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with `re.I` for ignore upper and lower cases and then add [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(x)) for x in dictionary['Lists'])

news['similar'] = news["STORY"].str.findall(pattern, flags=re.I).str.join(', ')
print (news)
   ID                                              STORY  exist/not exist  \
0   1  The weather today is Sunny, but tomorrow it is...                1   
1   2  In  UK, there are 4 seasons, winter,summer, au...                1   
2   3                          Food is essential in life                0   

                          similar  
0                    Sunny, rainy  
1  winter, summer, autumn, spring  
2
```

Or convert both values to lowercases by [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html):

```
news['similar'] = news["STORY"].str.lower().str.findall(pattern.lower()).str.join(', ')
print (news)
   ID                                              STORY  exist/not exist  \
0   1  The weather today is Sunny, but tomorrow it is...                1   
1   2  In  UK, there are 4 seasons, winter,summer, au...                1   
2   3                          Food is essential in life                0   

                          similar  
0                    sunny, rainy  
1  winter, summer, autumn, spring  
2
```

Comment: i got nothing in my similar column

Comment: @strawberrylatte - for both solutions?

Comment: @strawberrylatte - For me working nice, maybe some data related problem. Are data confidental? Is possible share it?

Comment: the data is actually not big, but i don't know where i can share it at

Comment: what is your email?

Comment: i have sent you my files

Comment: @strawberrylatte - tested.

Comment: i still got nothing in my similar column

Comment: @strawberrylatte - For me working `pattern = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(x)) for x in dictionary['Lists'])`